# Can't center layout (Using TableLayout)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to center my layout so there's an equal amount of space on the right and left side. Currently, everything is left aligned. I've tried setting layout_gravity to center_horizontal for all my widgets/elements but that doesn't work. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/scored"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:text="@string/percent"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />


            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="5"
                    android:inputType="number" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="5"
                    android:inputType="number" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="5"
                    android:inputType="number" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="5"
                    android:inputType="number" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="5"
                    android:inputType="number" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="5"
                    android:inputType="number" />

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/calculate" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove all other gravity attributes you set.

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"> <---- HERE
```

Comment: Awesome! It works! Except for one thing. My rows are now all centered except for my button. Why is that? I set the gravity to "center_horizontal" but it's still not centered.

Comment: One thing you dont recognize. There is a different between layout_gravity and gravity. Use gravity to set gravity in parent view to set gravity of its child layouts. And layout_gravity to set gravity to the layout itself.